# Using sed to replace the second instance of an entire line

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing a bash script and I want to find a certain string and replace the entire line but on the second occurrence.

For example:

```
# randomtext 9876
randomtext 9999
```

I want to replace the 2nd occurrence of "randomtext" with "randomtext 123". So the final output should be like this:

```
# randomtext 9876
randomtext 123
```

I found a solution online which is quite similar to what I want but I am unsure on how to use it.

```
sed -i "0,/^PATTERN/ s/^PATTERN=.*$/PATTERN=XY/" test.txt
```

Comment: You want to replace only the 2nd occurrence or you want to skip the first occurrence and change the rest?

Comment: I want to replace only the 2nd occurrence

Comment: Or do you want to replace only uncommented ones?

Comment: ohh it does make a difference? I want to replace only the uncommented one. Because in that file there is only 2 occurrences of the same word. But one is commented and one is uncommented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements aren't clear and your sample input/output isn't helping but given this input file:

```
$ cat file
# randomtext 9876
foo
randomtext 9999
bar
randomtext 3
```

To replace the 2nd occurrence of randomtext:

```
$ awk '{print (/randomtext/ && (++c==2) ? "randomtext 123" : $0)}' file
# randomtext 9876
foo
randomtext 123
bar
randomtext 3
```

To replace all uncommented occurrences of randomtext:

```
$ awk '{print (/^[^#]*randomtext/ ? "randomtext 123" : $0)}' file
# randomtext 9876
foo
randomtext 123
bar
randomtext 123
```

To replace the 1st uncommented occurrence of randomtext:

```
$ awk '{print (/^[^#]*randomtext/ && (++c==1) ? "randomtext 123" : $0)}' file
# randomtext 9876
foo
randomtext 123
bar
randomtext 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! What if I want to make changes to the file instead of printing it out, how do I do it using awk? Similar to sed -i.

Comment: With any UNIX command, `cmd`, to change the original file you can just do `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file`. That's all that GNU sed when using `sed -i 'script' file` does behind the scenes to save you from typing `sed 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`. With GNU awk 4.* you can do `awk -i inplace 'script' file` instead of having to type the few extra characters `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.